# Can I replace a battery with a higher capacity one?

Tags: batteries, repair

I have a pair of Sony WF-1000XM3 and after three years the batteries in them have significantly degraded.

The guides online suggest to get the following Battery:

```
VARTA CP1254 A3 - 3.7V / 0.2Wh / 60mAh
```

[data sheet](https://www.weisbauer.de/fileadmin/news/varta/180301/cp1254a3_ds.pdf)

The only ones that I can find on somewhat reputable resellers in Germany are these:

```
VARTA CP1254 A4 - 3.7V / 74 mAh
```

[data sheet](https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/002576667DS00/datenblatt-2576667-varta-knopfzellen-akku-cp1254-a4-li-ion-74-mah-37-v-1-st.pdf)

I know very little about electronics but as far as I can tell from the data sheets, the only difference between the two is the capacity and the weight. So my question is **can I use the A4 variant** as well?

---

**Edit** for future reference: I did the swap with the batteries I referenced above. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iG498JT3Y-k) tutorial and while it's not perfect, I got it done pretty easily.

Immediately after I installed the new battery, the touch inputs would make the sound that they registered an input, but the input wouldn't be registered by a connected device. This has since subsided (no idea what caused it).

Overall I'm again very happy with the performance and battery live of the device, although I can't really say if it's longer now than it was when I first got them originally.

Comment: What JYelton said. || The higher capacity battery will probably charge to a lightly HIGHER  percent of max capacity as the cutoff current in CCCV charging will be a lower percentage of capacity. This is unlikely to matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A battery with the same chemistry and voltage specifications but higher capacity will simply last longer. The charging circuit should still work, but there's a chance some firmware has been programmed to cut off charging after a given time limit or charge amount if a coulomb counter is used, but with a 14 mAh difference, it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: So "worst case" It won't use the additional available capacity?

Comment: @LukasKnuth Unlikely but possible. Please report back on your findings with a @ followed by username as I have the same issue.

Comment: @winny I did the switch a week ago and can confirm everything worked.

Comment: @LukasKnuth Many thanks!